# Where did all the activity on this question come from?

Tags: discussion, questions

The question [Do bigger or more monitors increase productivity?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1700/does-more-monitor-real-estate-really-increase-productivity) was asked yesterday, has **10k** views, and is one vote away from being the highest voted question on the site (**47** at the moment).

Where did all this activity come from?  I assume it was linked externally somewhere, but does anyone know where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was posted on [HackerNews](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2403565), which probably accounts for most of the traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff Atwood also [tweeted it](http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/54795008255074304) which accounts for another, smaller part of the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

It was also on one of the other SE pages before it was moved to skeptics.SE (programmers.SE, I think.)

Comment: I thought that it might have been, but if it did why doesn't it say migrated?

Comment: I might be mistaken.  The list of edit revisions shows that @Sklivvz created it '2 days ago'.

Answer (score 0):

It's a question about programming practice on which programmers mostly hold strong opinions. Given the demographics of StackExchange I'd be astonished if it didn't get high traffic. The tweets and links help too.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with traffic patterns on these sites and that many views doesn't just come from incidental visits to the home page.